# For loop + increment

Tags: javascript, loops, file, video

I'm basically trying to make my buttons work for each video, the videos are generated by the loop itself, fetching the files from my server with the loop as well.

My only problem are the buttons, the videos get generated fine.

I can't seem to wrap my head around the following line, maybe there's even more than just this line I'm not doing right.

```
var vid[i] = document.getElementById( + [i] + "myVideo");
```

Am I even doing this right?

```
<script>
var files = <?php $out = array();
foreach (glob('../medias/aPartager/visuel/*.mp4') as $filename) {
    $p = pathinfo($filename);
    $out[] = $p['filename'];
}
echo json_encode($out); 

?>;
var files, text, fLen, i;
fLen = files.length;
text = "";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
text += "<a href='#video'><button onclick='playVid(" + i + ")' type='button'>Play Video</button><button onclick='pauseVid(" + i + ")' type='button'>Pause Video</button><button onclick='enableControls(" + i + ")' type='button'>Enable controls</button><button onclick='disableControls(" + i + ")' type='button'>Disable controls</button><br><video id='" + i + "myVideo' class='video' width='320' height='240' controls><source src='../medias/aPartager/visuel/" + files[i] + "' type='video/mp4'>Votre navigateur ne prend pas en charge la balise vidéo.</video></a>";




  var vid[i] = document.getElementById( + [i] + "myVideo");

  function playVid(i) { 
    vid[i].play(i); 
  } 

  function pauseVid(i) { 
    vid[i].pause(i); 
  } 

  function enableControls(i) { 
    vid[i].controls = true;
    vid[i].load(i);
  } 

  function disableControls(i) { 
    vid[i].controls = false;
    vid[i].load(i);
  } 



}
text += "";

document.getElementById("lesVideos").innerHTML = text;
<script>
```

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi2bN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the functions for play inside the for loop. It need to be outside of the loop. Also `var vid[1]` is NOT valid

```js
function playVid(id) { 
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid(id) { 
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <button onclick="playVid('video-1')" type="button">Play Video</button>
  <button onclick="pauseVid('video-1')" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

  <video id="video-1" width="320" height="176">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
<div class="video">
  <button onclick="playVid('video-2')" type="button">Play Video</button>
  <button onclick="pauseVid('video-2')" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 
  <video id="video-2" width="320" height="176">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

OR other option

```
let videoMap = {}
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
 // Generate HTML first
 // Add the video to videoMap and cache it
  videoMap[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}
```

then AFTER the loop finishes to make it all work.

```
function playVid(id) { 
  videoList[id].play(); 
} 

function pauseVid(id) { 
  videoList[id].pause(); 
}
```